# Java 1.7 seems to show jPanels differently to other Java versions

Tags: java, swing

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but am currently writing my first java program (i have used other languages before), and am seeing something odd with the way my jPanel is displayed

Based on the information I have found on here, i have created a frame, a main jPanel, then 2 sub jPanels (jPanel1 and jPanel2) and am using cardlayout to change from jPanel1 to jPanel2 when a button is pressed....the button press also kicks off some code that does some stuff and updates a progress bar that I have on jPanel2

In netbeans I have uploaded Java 1.6, 1.7 AND 1.8 libraries. If i choose 1.6 or 1.8 all seems to work fine (same if i run on machines with those java versions installed)....but if i use 1.7, when i click the button, only the components on the jPanel2 get displayed, and some of the components from jPanel1 are still visible (those that aren't covered by the components from jPanel2)...the jPanel2 components get updated by the program correctly

Once the program has finished doing its thing, then jPanel2 gets shown correctly and jPanel1 components disappear from view

I have checked to make sure the jPanels are set to be opaque. I have tried removing components from jPanel1, redrawing, validating etc, but still it shows the same.

Is there some bug in 1.7 or should i be doing things differently (most likely :) )

If i don't run the program that does the stuff, so the button just changes the jPanels, then all looks OK in any Java version.

seems that maybe the program is locking some thread that is also related to jPanel1 so only once the program is complete, can jPanel1 disappear....would that sound right?....in which case what would be the best way to resolve?

(apologies for the long post and please treat as a complete newbie)

Requested info:
So my button code currently looks like this:

```
    private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Working...");
    jButtonClose.setEnabled(false);
    jPanel1.setVisible(false);


    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();
    card.show(mainPanel, "cardjPanel2");
    jPanel2.setFocusable(true);
    jPanel2.requestFocus();


    //MainFrame. //TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

While I was trying to work around the issue, i've currently got my program method being called when jPanel2 gets the focus, so that piece of code just looks like this:

```
    private void jPanel2FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    

    runprogram();
}
```

Here is what the problem looks like:

Screen 1 when the program is run
[image: Screen 1 when the program is run:]

When OK is pressed and jPanel2 is displayed, it looks like this while the program is running (progress bar moves correctly during program execution)
[image: When OK is pressed and jPanel2 is displayed, it looks like this while the program is running (progress bar moves correctly during program execution):]

Below is the code from my .java file that recreates the jPanels, then when OK is pressed, swaps to jPanel2, then updates the progress bar every second. As you can see, when OK is pressed, OK and Cancel are still visible (as are some of the texts fields). Once the program has finished, then jPanel2 is displayed correctly.

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author PBETTS
 */
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public static String agentinforesult;

/**
 * Creates new form MainFrame
 */
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabelpmhost = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabelvchost = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabelarhost = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabelmthost = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextFieldpmhost = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextFieldvchost = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextFieldarhost = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextFieldmthost = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButtonOK = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButtonCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButtonClose = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
    jLabelinfo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 400));
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 400));
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowActivated(evt);
        }
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowOpened(evt);
        }
    });

    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(530, 313));
    mainPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(530, 313));

    jLabelpmhost.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabelpmhost.setText("PM Hostname");

    jLabelvchost.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabelvchost.setText("vCenter/Hyper-V Hostname");

    jLabelarhost.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabelarhost.setText("AR Hostname");

    jLabelmthost.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabelmthost.setText("Mid Tier Hostname");

    jTextFieldpmhost.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jTextFieldvchost.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jTextFieldarhost.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jTextFieldarhost.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextFieldarhostActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextFieldmthost.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jTextFieldmthost.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextFieldmthostActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButtonOK.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButtonOK.setText("OK");
    jButtonOK.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonOKActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButtonCancel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButtonCancel.setText("Cancel");
    jButtonCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonCancelActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setText("Environment Checker");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(15, 15, 15)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 97, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButtonOK, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(90, 90, 90)
                    .addComponent(jButtonCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(88, 88, 88))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabelpmhost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabelarhost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabelvchost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabelmthost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextFieldvchost)
                        .addComponent(jTextFieldpmhost)
                        .addComponent(jTextFieldarhost)
                        .addComponent(jTextFieldmthost))))
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(168, 168, 168))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabelpmhost)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldpmhost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabelvchost)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldvchost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabelarhost)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldarhost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabelmthost)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldmthost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButtonCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButtonOK, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    mainPanel.add(jPanel1, "cardjPanel1");

    jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(530, 313));
    jPanel2.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            jPanel2FocusGained(evt);
        }
    });

    jButtonClose.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButtonClose.setText("Close");
    jButtonClose.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonCloseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jProgressBar1.setOpaque(true);

    jLabelinfo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 17)); // NOI18N

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel3.setText("Environment Checker");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabelinfo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(206, 206, 206)
                    .addComponent(jButtonClose, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 148, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(168, 168, 168))
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(jLabelinfo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(38, 38, 38)
            .addComponent(jButtonClose, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(23, 23, 23))
    );

    mainPanel.add(jPanel2, "cardjPanel2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 640, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    JLabel test = new JLabel("test", JLabel.LEFT);

    jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Working...");
    jButtonClose.setEnabled(false);


    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();
    card.show(mainPanel, "cardjPanel2");
    jPanel2.setFocusable(true);
    jPanel2.requestFocus();


    //MainFrame. //TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void jTextFieldarhostActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  // *** this will center your app ***
    //jPanel1.setVisible(true);
    //jPanel2.setVisible(false);
```

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                    

private void jTextFieldmthostActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                

private void jButtonCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    System.exit(0); // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

private void jPanel2FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    

    runprogram();
}                                   

private void jButtonCloseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    System.exit(0);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                            

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonCancel;
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonClose;
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonOK;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelarhost;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelinfo;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelmthost;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelpmhost;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelvchost;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldarhost;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldmthost;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldpmhost;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldvchost;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
// End of variables declaration
```

private void test(){

}

private void runprogram(){

```
               //Execute when button is pressed
            //System.out.println("You clicked the button");

    jProgressBar1.setValue(2);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Creating Report folder and subdirectories");
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(4);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Getting OS of remote server"); 
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(10);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Retrieving Information from Platform Manager");
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(20);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Retrieving Information from the VC/Hyper-V server");
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(30);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Retrieving Information from AR server");   
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(40);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Retrieving Information from Mid Tier server");  
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect()); 

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(50);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Analysing data from the Platform Manager");  
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(60);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Analysing data from the AR server");  
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(70);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Analysing data from the VC/Hyper-V");  
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(80);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Analysing data from the BSA server");    
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(90);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Analysing data from the Mid Tier server");  
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(95);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Comparing values with tuning guide and creating Report.xlsx");  
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    jProgressBar1.setValue(100);
    jLabelinfo.setText("Analysing data Complete. Please check the Report folder");
    jProgressBar1.paintImmediately(jProgressBar1.getVisibleRect());
    jLabelinfo.paintImmediately(jLabelinfo.getVisibleRect());


    jButtonClose.setEnabled(true); 
    jPanel2.setFocusable(false);
```

}

}

Comment: code + screenshots of what you are experiencing

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: sure, let me get them for you....hang on :)

Comment: i've now added those to the original post...

Comment: Ensure that all cards, JPanels, are of maximal size - BorderLayout maybe, because that seems to be the problem.

Comment: jPanel1 and jPanel2 are the same size, so i would have assumed jPanel2 would sit right on top of jPanel1 hiding any of its components...

Comment: *"..i've now added those.."* I suggest (again) to post a [mcve] (and I mean that, instead of uncompilable code snippets). Note that there are 2 separate close reasons that mention 'no MCVE', and this post has already got 3 of 5 close votes. And a tip: Add @Tschallacka (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: apologies @AndrewThompson, I have created a new project, stripped out all my code, so all it does when you click OK is swap to jPanel2, then step through updating the progress bar every second....problem is reproduced, i'll add the code to this question now...

Comment: *"i'll add the code to this question now."* Is there something about 'minimal' that you are having trouble understanding? It should not take 533 lines of code to describe the problem in code. I imagine it could be done in less than 200 LOC if you really set your mind to it! Now, have at it..

Comment: @AndrewThompson all you need to do is cut and paste....its already cut down from the many thousands of lines my code currently has....if you don't wish to help that is fine....i can work around it a bit by resizing the text field and progress bar and removing borders between them (thanks Joop Eggen)....but the buttons still show....sometimes i can compile and run it and it works fine, other times when i run it i still see the problem....looks like a bug to me.

Comment: *"all you need to do is.."* I'm going to stop you there, as you seem to be under a misunderstanding that any of us *need* to do *anything* (beyond not break the site rules). It's your problem, you're the one that needs to enthuse people into helping. For us, it is purely academic. We'll help if we feel like it, and dumping >500 LOC certainly does not make me 'feel like' helping. Best of luck with *your* problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, i'm not under the impression that you (or anyone else) need to do anything at all, i appreciate all the comments received and any help/advice given....as it happens, i've finally found the answer. I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that if i add the following to the OK button code before the program runs, that the problem is resolved:

```
jPanel2.paintImmediately(jPanel2.getVisibleRect());
```